# Hadoop: Parse file from DistributedCache

Tags: hadoop

What's a good way to read in a file from the `DistributedCache` using the newer Hadoop API? I've placed the file in the `DistributedCache` with this line in my driver code:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("c1.txt"), getConf());
```

I'd like to access the contents of `c1.txt` in my Mapper's `setup` function.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can just open it and read it in the `setup()` method:

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("c1.txt");
```

I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: Yup, just read them from the current working directory like any other file. "Distributed Cache associates the cache files to the current working directory of the mapper and reducer using symlinks." - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-input-distributed-cache.html